# How To Create a Percentage Conversion Graph in GA4?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I'm struggling to create a simple conversion percentage graph in Google Analytics 4 (GA4) for an event named "CTA Click". I have shared a screenshot of what the business objectives > conversions section looks like in my GA4 setup:

[image]

However, the absolute conversion numbers aren't quite helpful for my analysis, and I'm trying to convert this data into a percentage graph. Here's a detailed description of my unsuccessful attempts:

1. **Editing the Existing Graph:** My initial approach was to edit the existing graph to display the conversion percentage for the "CTA Click" event. However, I discovered that there isn't a straightforward metric or option to display this as a percentage. I tried using the 'user conversion rate' metric, but it only added a column to the table without affecting the graph. Additionally, this metric displayed a 100% conversion rate, which is clearly inaccurate.
2. **Exploring the Free Form Report:** I then moved to the 'Explore' section to try out a free form report. My intention was to add metrics like user conversion rates and graph them. However, this approach also hit a roadblock. The report did not specify the event associated with the conversion rates, leading to a lack of clarity. Even after pulling in the event name and applying a filter for the "CTA Click" event, the conversion rate still erroneously showed as 100%.

Throughout these attempts, I've found GA4 to be somewhat buggy and not as user-friendly as expected, especially when trying to achieve something that seems basic.

I'm reaching out to the community for guidance on how to effectively create a conversion percentage graph for a specific event in GA4. Any insights or step-by-step instructions would be greatly appreciated!

Here's a link to the screen recording of my attempts for more context: [Screen Recording](https://app.usebubbles.com/ehgYeNWtcvqmZNPTt3ixQU/ga-4-creating-basic-conversion-graph)